# check if my whole year dataset contains all months and days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got the 1 year data and I would like to check if it contains observations from every day of every month. Basically to validate if all has been collected.
The dataset contains day, month and year column. My idea was to plot this and see if all days of months are there.  I have tried the following

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(earth2019['month'], earth2019['day'])

plt.show()
```

but the chart doesn't really confirms what I wanted to know,

My question is how to validate that my  data contains all the observations? it should have some observations for each day of each month, I basically want to know if all data has been collected in that dataset.
Is there some way to check this using Python code?

Comment: Please, update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string())`.

Comment: does it have just one data per day? If so, just count the rows

Comment: no it may have several per day but for sure there should be at least one observation for each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample, it's difficult but you can try:

```
ref19 = pd.date_range('2019', '2020', closed='left', freq='D')
dti19 = pd.to_datetime(earth2019.assign(year=2019)[['year', 'month', 'day']])

out = ref19.difference(dti19)  # missing dates here
```

Sample output:

```
>>> out
DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-20', '2019-04-02', '2019-04-13', '2019-04-26',
               '2019-05-08', '2019-07-19', '2019-09-21', '2019-10-09',
               '2019-10-11', '2019-12-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Yes it does! I think! I got the following after printing out: DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-31'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None), does this mean that there is only one day missing in the whole 2019? If that is the case, wonderful

Comment: Yes, the output is actually the missing days.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.The dataset contains day, month and year column
>
> > 2. check if it contains observations from every day of every month.
> >
> > > 3.validate if all has been collected.

```
df.Yr_Mo_Dy.head()

df.Yr_Mo_Dy.value_counts()

df.Yr_Mo_Dy.isnull().sum()
```